# Curious Sample Correlation Property

Tags: distributions, correlation

I'm examining correlations in a data set with a large number of variables but small sample sizes. To get a feel for how these quantities behave, I generated some random data and looked at the distribution of correlations:

```
n = 4
y = matrix(rnorm(1000 * n), 1000, n)
x = matrix(rnorm(1000 * n), 1000, n)
p = as.numeric(cor(t(x),t(y)))
hist(p)
```

To my surprise, the distribution is almost perfectly uniform:
[image: histogram]

Does anyone have an explanation for this phenomenon? It makes some sense in that for n=2 we have either p=1 or p=-1, and as n->infinity the distribution becomes normal, so this distribution falls somewhere inbetween. But why uniform? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For independent Normal variates, the distribution of the correlation coefficient $r$ is proportional to $(1 - r^2)^{{1\over2} (n-4)}dr$.  When $n=4$, that's uniform.

#### Reference

R. A. Fisher, [Frequency-distribution of the values of the correlation coefficient in samples from an indefinitely large population](http://www.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta215/lec/Fish1915.pdf).  *Biometrika*, **10**, 507.  See Section 3.  (Quoted in *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*, 5th Ed., section 16.24.)

Comment: Thanks! I was sure it was a well-known result, but I wasn't able to find it myself. I appreciate the reference too; academic writing was so much more colorful back then...